# Display regions in user-profile.tpl.php

Tags: blocks, users, theming

I created a region into `mytheme.info`

```
regions[list_user_poke] = List User Poke
```

I put a block in it. Then I want to print this region `user-profile.tpl.php`.
I wrote this chode :

```
<div class="list-user">
   <?php print render($page['list_user_poke']); ?>
  </div>
```

But it does not appear.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering about this, here's how to do it (code goes in your theme's `template.php` file):

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
  $variables['YOUR_NODE_REGION'] = block_get_blocks_by_region('YOUR_NODE_REGION');
}
```

And then in your `user-profile.tpl.php` template:

```
<?php if ($YOUR_NODE_REGION): ?>
  <div class="custom-region">
    <?php print render($YOUR_NODE_REGION); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```